# How to set up SAMBA / CUPS print server?

Tags: server, 13.04, printing, samba, windows-8

I am using 13.04 on an old laptop hooked up to a printer that I would like to access from my Windows 8 PC. I have been working on this for hours and I cannot seem to get the right configuration of SAMBA and CUPS to make it work. I had it working once before but I had to re-install for an unrelated reason. Did not think of backing up the configuration files...

Anyways, I would like to be able to go onto my windows computer open up the network folder and see the server show up. Then when I open the server, for it to show me all the printers connected to that computer. And finally, to be able to install and print right from there.

I have searched hours and tried multiple solutions but none seem to work. As soon as I get a reasonable answer, I will wipe my current configuration and start from scratch, so that none of my work will interfere with the solution.

Please when you answer make sure to start from the beginning. As I will not have a single thing set up. (e.g.  list all commands, program requirements, etc)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ubuntu based equivalent -if not better called Zentyal and can be either installed as an appliance or on top of a Ubuntu installation (Zentyal-Samba and Zentyal-Printers)

More details [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/zentyal.html)